# Angular - ViewChild(Directive) returns undefined in Directive

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular V7.x

I am creating a Directive that adds a dynamic component to the specified container. I am using another Directive to mark as an insertion point but, ViewChild() returns undefined no matter what. Even if it's accessed in `ngAfterViewInit`. Angular Docs example accesses ViewChild in `ngOnInit`, though.

**alert.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ViewChild, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertHostDirective } from './alert-host.directive';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAlert]'
})
export class AlertDirective {
  @ViewChild(AlertHostDirective) alertHost;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.alertHost); // undefined
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.alertHost); // undefined
  }

  @Input() set appAlert(name: string) {
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  }
}
```

**alert-host.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAlertHost]'
})
export class AlertHostDirective {

  constructor() { }

}
```

**form-signup.html**

```
<form *appAlert="'signupForm'" class="form-signup" (submit)="onSubmit($event)" [formGroup]="signupForm">
      <h2 class="mb-4">Sign Up &mdash; it's free</h2>
      <ng-template appAlertHost></ng-template>
      ... (more content)
</form>
```

StackBlitz Link: [VIEW ON STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wizxcc)

Answer (score 2):

Since your AlertHostDirective is not used in a component's HTML Template but between the form's opening and form's closing tags, you'll need to use [ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild) to get access to your Directive.

Comment: Still `undefined`.

Comment: the problem seems to be that you use AlertDirective as [structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives). If you use it without the asterisk, it works. Is there any need for?
See updates blitzstack: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxcwxr?file=src%2Fapp%2Falert.directive.ts